# Compare values and add error class to the words that doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare, comparison

I'm comparing two values with javascript/jQuery. One value is the data attribute and the other one is what user is typing. I want script to find word in user value that doesn't match word in the data attribute. I can add class to the whole .text element, but I don't know how to add class to the words... Should I split these values?

Here's my HTML code

```
<div id="compare-text">
  <div class="row"><span>1.</span><p class="text" data-for="Some sample text" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"></p></div>
  <div class="row"><span>2.</span><p class="text" data-for="Some sample text" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"></p></div>
  <div class="row"><span>3.</span><p class="text" data-for="Some sample text" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"></p></div>
</div>
```

Here's my script

```
$('#check').click(function () {
var controlNumber = 1;
$('.text').each(function () {
  var value = $(this).attr('data-for'),
    userValue = $(this).text();
  value = value.toLowerCase();
  userValue = userValue.toLowerCase();
  if (userValue === '') {
    $(this).addClass('error');
    $(this).removeClass('success');
    controlNumber = 0;
  } else if (value !== userValue && userValue !== '') {
    $(this).addClass('error');
    $(this).removeClass('success');
    controlNumber = 0;
  } else if (value === userValue) {
    $(this).addClass('success');
    $(this).removeClass('error');
  } else {
    controlNumber = 1;
  }
});
if (controlNumber === 1) {
  $('#success-message').addClass('visible');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the typed data matches the `data-for` attributes value, you can do this:

```
$(".test").keydown(function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('data-for').split(" "),
        text = this.value.split(0);
    $(this).addClass("success");
    $(this).removeClass("error");
    for (var i = text.length; i--;) for (var j = data.length; j--;) {
        if (data[j] === text[i])  {
            $(this).addClass("error");
            $(this).removeClass("success");
    }
})
```

Change the `test` elements to inputs such as:

`<input/>` or `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: Should I paste this code inside the #check click function?

Comment: @user3043693 IMO you should never paste code you do not understand... what's you doubt about this?